# Laravel API Request - Not able to display Posted Data/Passed Parameters

Tags: laravel

I need help on my Laravel API,

I have an external API Request written in C#

Method: Post
Data is JSON which is being posted to my Laravel API URL: http://localhost/project/api/company-data

API route:

```
Route::post('company-data', 'API\APIController@index');
```

Here is my API Controllers index() function

```
 public function index(Request $request)
    {
        
       return var_dump($request->all());
    }
```

My API Call is hitting the function since I was able to capture it on logs,
However it is returning me an empty array?
How do I catch the json data that was posted to my API?

Thank You for your help, my apologies if I cannot explain my concern clearly,

Comment: please check your middleware

Comment: is the request sending the correct headers?

Comment: It appears your request is empty. Your code seems to be OK.

Answer (score 0):

If found the solution,
It is $Request should be

```
json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
```

instead of

```
$request->all()
```